# How to interpolate scattered data in matab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, runtime-error, interpolation

I have two-dimensional data in Matlab. The X values and the Y values aren't distributed uniformly, so I can't use the `interp2` function.

As far as I understand, I should use the `griddata` function. Here is how I do it:

```
%//x_val  - my x values, of size, lets say, 32 by 1;
%//y_val - my y values,  of size, let's say, 128 by 1;
%//f_val - values of my function, of size 32 by 128.
%//[x,y] - the point in which I want to get the interpolated value of my function.

result = griddata(x_val,y_val,f_val,x,y);
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error using griddata (line 109)
>
> The lengths of X and Y must match the size of Z.

It seems to me that I'm using the interpolation in 3D (`griddata(x,y,z,v,xq,yq,zq)`), instead of 2D (`griddata(x,y,v,xq,yq)`), but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

What is the correct way of using *griddata*? What's wrong with my code?

I have looked over [the examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html), however, I can't figure out how they relate to my issue.

Comment: As the error message says, you want the lengths of `xval` and `y_val` to be equal to the size of `f_val`. What are the sizes of these variables? Also you're using 2D not 3Das you have `f` as a function of `x` and `y`

Comment: When you say 2D data do you mean like a normal line chart or like a surface plot? Because you still need Z-data for a 2D interpolation because the 2D refers to the x and y coordinates of each point and the the z is the value found at that point (like a surface plot)

Comment: Based on the dimensions that you've provided, you **don't** have scattered data. If it were scattered you'd have a unique x,y for every f. You can use `meshgrid` or `ndgrid` to create your `x` and `y` prior to calling `griddata`

Comment: @Suever, what I mean is that my x values and y values aren't distributed uniformly. My x vector doesn't look like 1:32, it's more or less like 1:0.1:9.9 and 10:100 (for example). And I'm not sure I get your second comment. If I had a unique x and y for each f, my function would be injective, but why would that matter?

Comment: @Dan, when I say 2D data, I mean that my function has two arguments: f(x,y). I know that I need z as the function value. Sorry I wasn't precise.

Comment: @user2738748 Right, I definitely understand that. The issue is that `griddata` expects `x_val` to have a length of 4096 (the same number of elements as `f_val`) and same for `y_val`. If you check out my answer you can see how to do that concisely.

Comment: @Suever, then why isn't my data scattered?

Comment: @user2738748 You're right, it is technically scattered.

Comment: @Suever, I understand. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, you have data on a non-uniform grid; however, `griddata` expects a unique `x` and `y` value for every value of the function (`f_val`). So you'll need to use [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to create these unique combinations of `x` and `y`.

```
[xx,yy] = ndgrid(x_val, y_val);
result = griddata(xx(:), yy(:), f_val(:), x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.